# Angular @Input set programmatically for 3rd party controls

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, primeng

I am using *PrimeNG* controls.  I am setting the disabled attribute on various input controls via a directive and some of the controls are p-dropdown, p-listbox and p-calendar PrimeNG controls.  The basic input, textarea and select controls work just find, but the *PrimeNG* controls have disable defined as **@Input** as follows:

```
private _disabled: boolean;

@Input() get disabled(): boolean {
    return this._disabled;
};
```

and a code snippet of the directive is as follows:

```
/*
** find all inputs and disable them.
*/
disableElements( el: ElementRef ): void {
    const controls = el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll( 'input, select, textarea, p-dropdown, p-listbox, p-checkbox' );
    controls.forEach( (elmt: any) => {
        this.disableElement( elmt );
    });
}
/*
** disable an input element.
*/
disableElement( elmt: any ): void {
    if( elmt.localName.substr(0,2) === 'p-' ) {
        this._renderer.setProperty(elmt, 'disabled', 'true');
    } else {
        if(!elmt.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
            this._renderer.setAttribute(elmt, 'disabled', 'true');
        }
    }
}
```

So, how to disable the *PrimeNG* 3rd party controls given a **ElementRef.nativeElement**?  I am thinking, I need a way to fulfill the disabled **@Input** property given an element reference.

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: So, how to disable the PrimeNG 3rd party controls given an ElementRef.nativeElement?  Thanks

Comment: are you able to disable any input now.. or getting any error

Comment: I can disable input, select and textarea.  I cannot disable p-dropdown, p-listbox and p-calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I don't think that it's a good idea to disable controls programmatically using a directive, I totally recommend you to handle it using good-old inputs instead.

But I can propose a following solution for your situation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-prime-ng-elements

The solution itself is not perfect - but it's a tradeoff if you don't want to work with `disabled` inputs.

1. Firstly, create a directive called `PrimeNgComponentsChangeDetectorRefDirective` to get a public version of primeng components' change detector to update their views. You should manually include all the primeng components that you want to handle. The trick here is to use the same selector to automatically match primeng components.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'p-checkbox, p-dropdown, p-listbox'
})
export class PrimeNgComponentsChangeDetectorRefDirective {
  public hostComponent: Checkbox | Dropdown | Listbox;

  constructor(
    public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    @Optional() private checkbox: Checkbox,
    @Optional() private dropdown: Dropdown,
    @Optional() private listbox: Listbox
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.hostComponent = this.getHostComponent();
  }

  private getHostComponent() {
    return [this.checkbox, this.dropdown, this.listbox].find(
      component => !!component
    );
  }
}
```

2. Then, in your disabling directive implement following properties and methods:

```
  @ContentChildren(PrimeNgComponentsChangeDetectorRefDirective)
  private componentsQuery: QueryList<
    PrimeNgComponentsChangeDetectorRefDirective
  >;

  disablePrimeNgComponents() {
    const components = this.componentsQuery.toArray();

    components.forEach(component => {
      component.hostComponent.disabled = true;
      component.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

We need to `detectChanges` manually because we have changed `disabled` property programmatically and angular knows nothing about this change.

Comment: Brilliant. Not fond of setTimeout, Changed hostComponent to a getter and returned getHostComponent.

Comment: yeah, setTimeout was just to check that the solution is working

Comment: lint is not happy with above selector of 'p-checkbox, p-dropdown, p-listbox', stating **directive-selector  The selector should be used as an attribute (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-06)**

Comment: Hey, I just implemented security and started to use it and it does not handle PrimeNG controls inside of div tags.